# Custom two way binding and @Input mismatch in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've read an [*article*](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) about two way binding in Angular.
Also - Angular docs provide an example of accessing a property of an inner component.

In the parent component it has :

```
 <name-child *ngFor="let name ..." [name]="name"></name-child>
```

Where `[name]` refers to the inner *setter*(!):

```
 @Input()
 set name(name: string) {
    this._name =...;
  }
```

This is pretty clear.

But then I saw the following example [*(here)*](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html):

```
<custom-counter [(counter)]="counterValue"></custom-counter>
```

Where `counter` is in the inner component as @Input on a GETTER !

```
    @Input()       // <--------     On a getter ??
    get counter()
    {
        return this.counterValue;
    }

    set counter(val)
    {
        this.counterValue = val;
        this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
    }
```

**Question**

The code in the plnkr does work as expected , Yet -  I don't understand how can it work with an `@Input` on a getter !

I mean - the parent should SET the value to the inner setter.

What am I missing ?

[**PLNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KIsIlU?p=preview)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%40Input()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%3C--------%20%20%20%20%20On%20a%20getter%20%3F%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20counter()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.counterValue%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%20counter(val)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.counterValue%20%3D%20val%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: @yurzui So it doesn't matter on which I set it ? ( edit , testing , same generated code - so it doesn't matter)

Comment: Seems like so. You can move decorator to setter but only one property will be created and therefore will be decorated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check what typescript does internally by using [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)

For example this code:

```
class MyClass {
    @Input()       // <--------     On a getter ??
    get counter()
    {
        return this.counterValue;
    }

    set counter(val)
    {
        this.counterValue = val;
        this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
    }
}
```

will be translated to

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    Object.defineProperty(MyClass.prototype, "counter", {
        get: function () {
            return this.counterValue;
        },
        set: function (val) {
            this.counterValue = val;
            this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return MyClass;
}());
__decorate([
    Input() // <--------     On a getter ??
], MyClass.prototype, "counter", null);
```

As you can see there is only one property with name counter and it will be decorated with @Input decorator.

Comment: _BTW I do play quite a lot with TS playground , but it didn't cross my mind to see about  decorators and how it affect in TS_. TIL.